# How to pass values to method in uiautomator android through runtest command line argument

Tags: android

```
    public void testAppByName(String appName) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        screenUnlocker();
        // String appName = "Clock";
        UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().description("Apps"));
        allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps"));
        appsTab.click();

        UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(
                new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

        UiObject appLaunch = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
                .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), appName);
        appLaunch.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
    }
```

How to provide values to method using uiautomator runtest command
I tried to execute the below command  adb shell uiautomator >runtest LaunchAppByName.jar -c >com.motorola.launchappbyname.LaunchAppByName#testAppByName -e String Clock  I am getting error it.framework.AssertionFailedError: Method "testAppByName" not found

Answer (score 7):

To pass params to the test case, the uiautomator says:

```
-e <NAME> <VALUE>: other name-value pairs to be passed to test classes.
    May be repeated.
```

for example you can do something like this:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest UiTest.jar -c package.name.ClassName -e stringKey stringValue
```

in the code you can use

```
String stringValue = getParams().getString("stringKey");
```

the `getString('key')` will return what ever you wrote as stringValue

Answer (score 1):

To use the extras supplied from adb command,
modify your function as below,

```
public void testAppByName() {
  getParams().getString("appName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass multiple parameters, you may use

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest UiTest.jar -c package.name.ClassName -e stringKey1 stringValue -e stringKey2 stringValue -e stringKey3 stringValue
```

Comment: The command which you have give here is not working dude, My executing exits when running like this